# RxJS handle multiple database connections

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, events, rxjs, emitter

this is the scenario:

I have multiple connection to different databases and i want to be sure that code runs whenever all connections are active.

I am using Rxjs to handle this (another solution is welcome ) but im facing that if i combine the connection events AFTER one of them is active i never get the subscription run, since combineLatest wants all observables to be emitted, but they were !

```js
const a = new Rx.Subject();
const b = new Rx.Subject();

var bool = false;

setInterval(()=>{
    bool = !bool
    a.next(bool ? ' i am connected' : 'im NOT connected');
},1000)

setTimeout(()=>{
    b.next('i am always connected!')
},400)

// this variable will be exported to all js that run queries
var obs = new Rx.Observable.combineLatest(a,b);

setTimeout(()=>{
    obs.subscribe((andb)=>{
        console.log( andb )
        // i can check all connections at once and run the code
    })
},399)

// problem is here, i want to subscribe later than the connections 
//emit, if you edit 399 to 401 you will see that nothing is going on
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

With a timeout of 399 you subscribe before `b` emits so you see its value.
With a timeout of 401 you subscribe after `b` emits so you don't see its value or that of `a` since `combineLatest` requires both. `combineLatest` wont keep track of the latest value for `a` and `b` till there is a subscription.

So you could use a different kind of subject that tracks the last value (`BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`) or use the `repeat` operator.

Here is an example with `ReplaySubject(1)` (basically same as BehaviorSubject but doesn't require an initial value) and subscribe at 401:

```js
const a = new Rx.Subject();
const b = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);

var bool = false;

setInterval(()=>{
    bool = !bool
    a.next(bool ? ' i am connected' : 'im NOT connected');
},1000)

setTimeout(()=>{
    b.next('i am always connected!')
},400)

// this variable will be exported to all js that run queries
var obs = new Rx.Observable.combineLatest(a,b);

setTimeout(()=>{
    obs.subscribe((andb)=>{
        console.log( andb )
        // i can check all connections at once and run the code
    })
},401)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , i can't find those type of subjects in rxjs 5 , what is the best approach with the latest version?

Comment: @ÆndriDomi Those subjects exist in the latest version of rxjs. I'll add your example with rxjs 5 to my answer.

Comment: You are right ! can you please explain me differences between subjects ?

Comment: @ÆndriDomi It's better to ask a separate question if your original question has been answered. That way the question can be useful to others. Do some research yourself, and if you can't figure it out, pose a new question showing what code you have tried.

Comment: @ÆndriDomi Yeah, you probably don't want a ReplaySubject without a buffer size or it will replay all messages. I updated the example to have a buffer size of 1. `ReplaySubject(1)` is effectively the same as the `BehaviorSubject` except that the BehaviorSubject requires an initial value.